# binary -> UTF-8 -> string

Tags: python, utf-8, encode

I'm trying to understand Unicode and all asociated things. I have made an utf-8.txt file which obviously is encoded in utf-8. It has "Hello world!" inside.
Heres what I do:

```
f = open('utf8.txt', mode = 'r', encoding = 'utf8')
f.read()
```

What I get is: '\ufeffHello world!' where did the prefix came from?

Another try:

```
f = open('utf8.txt', 'rb')
byte = f.read()
```

printing byte gives: b'\xef\xbb\xbfHello world!' I assume that prefix came in as hex.

```
byte.decode('utf8')
```

above code again gives me: '\ufeffHello world!'

What am I doing wrong? How to retrive text to python from utf-8 file?

Thanks for feedback!

Comment: Whatever editor you used to save the file, it added an UTF-8 BOM at the beginning of the file, which is explicitly discouraged. Get a better editor.

Comment: Bear in mind, `"Hello world!"` is UTF-8, ASCII, ISO-8859-1, ISO-8859-15, Windows-1252 etc etc etc. Things only getting interesting after `0x7F`

Answer (score 7):

Your utf-8.txt is encoded utf-8-bom which is different from utf-8. For an utf-8-bom file, '\uFEFF' is written into the beginning of the file. Instead of using `encoding = 'utf8'`, try `encoding = 'utf-8-sig'`

```
f = open('utf8.txt', mode = 'r', encoding = 'utf-8-sig')
print (f.read())
```

Comment: To explain, `utf-8-sig` is a special codec, which automatically removes the BOM on read and adds it on write.